# SQL: how to compare data in different rows and only select unique "pairs" assuming there are only two colums?

Tags: sql, select, group-by, selection

I have several tables (**bold** means primary key):

> Dancer(**dancer_name,** gender, age)
>
> Dance(**dancer_name, dvd_id,** song_title)
>
> Dvd(**dvd_id,** song_title, cost)
>
> Song(**dancer_name, song_title,** genre)
>
> Launch(**dancer_name, dvd_id,** year)

I want to select the pairs of dancers whose song appear together in one or more dvds and for each pair to only print out once.

This is as close as I could get and it prints out the same pair twice, but their names in different columns:

```
select distinct DANCER1.dancer_name, DANCER2.dancer_name, count(*) as count
  from Dancer DANCER1, Dancer DANCER2, Dance DANCE1, Dance DANCE2
 where DANCER1.dancer_name = DANCE1.dancer_name 
   and DANCER2.dancer_name = DANCE2.dancer_name 
   and DANCER1.dancer_name <> DANCER2.dancer_name
   and DANCE1.dvd_id = DANCE2.dvd_id
 group by DANCER1.dancer_name, DANCER2.dancer_name;
```

**So instead of getting**

```
Tom Jon
Jon Tom
Bob Sam
Sam Bob
```

**I just want**

```
Tom Jon
Bob Sam
```

Comment: As an architectural note, you may not want to use the `name` as your primary key

Comment: Could you provide your set of test values? [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3) can help you to do so. Also, wich RDBMS are you using? And why are you posting DVD, Song and Launch tables, they are not used on the query.

Comment: your dance_name data type is text?

Comment: @hd1- I didn't think about the name as primary key. Thanks!

Comment: Yaroslav- Thanks so much for sharing that SQL Fiddle tool!  I'm using and older version of DB2.  A sample table for dance is (Bob Hope, 1, New Year); a sample table for dancer is (Bob Hope, M, 25). I thought it might be helpful if i showed the whole database in case I just wasn't seeing something in another table that would have been easier to query.
Alex- dancer_name is VARCHAR(30)

Answer (score 3):

If you change the test from `DANCER1.dancer_name <> DANCER2.dancer_name` to `DANCER1.dancer_name < DANCER2.dancer_name`, you should get the result you want.

Hovever, as you are using the names as keys in the Dance table, you don't need to join the Dancer table, and the query may be simplified to this:

```
SELECT DANCE1.dancer_name, DANCE2.dancer_name, count(*) as count
FROM Dance DANCE1
INNER JOIN Dance DANCE2
ON DANCE1.dvd_id = DANCE2.dvd_id
WHERE DANCE1.dancer_name < DANCE2.dancer_name
GROUP by DANCE1.dancer_name, DANCE2.dancer_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @tmpTable table
(
    ID BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1),
    User1 BIGINT,
    User2 BIGINT
)

declare @tmpParticipants table
(
    Participant1 BIGINT,
    Participant2 BIGINT
)

insert into @tmpTable
Select distinct SendByID, SendToID
from InternalMessaging

declare @cnt bigint, @i bigint = 1, @user1 bigint, @user2 bigint

select @cnt = count(*) from @tmpTable

While(@i <= @cnt)
begin
        select @user1 = User1, @user2 = User2 from @tmpTable where ID = @i

        if not exists(select 1 from @tmpParticipants where Participant1 = @user1 and Participant2 = @user2)
        if not exists(select 1 from @tmpParticipants where Participant1 = @user2 and Participant2 = @user1)
        begin
                insert into @tmpParticipants
                select @user1, @user2
        end

        set @i = @i + 1
end

select * from @tmpParticipants
```

It worked for me. I hope, it will help to resolve your problem.